# update organization details is failing in google admin directory (users) api

Tags: google-directory-api

I'm trying update organization in users api,for this api

PUT [https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/{userKey}](https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/%7BuserKey%7D)

request:

```
{
        "userKey": "useremai@email.net",
        "name": {
            "familyName": "username1",
            "givenName": "username1"
        },
        "organizations": [
            {
                "name": "My Organization",
                "title": "Manager",
                "department": "Sales"
            }
        ]
    }
```

but getting this bellow error message.

```
{ "code": 400, "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "message": "Required parameter: [resource.im.field[0].Value]", "reason": "required" } ]
```

can we update the organization details in this api, what is the correct request.